# How can I give these two functions access to shared data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, closures

I have three functions, `handleSubmit` `handleCancel`, and `solve`. `HandleSubmit` triggers a compute-heavy process, `solve`. `handleCancel` should stop that process early.

My simplified code looks like this:

```
function handleSubmit() {
  computeHeavyProcess();
}
```

```
function handleCancel() {
  // not sure what to put here, or how to design this
}
```

```
function solve() {
  while (computationNotDone) {
    // do computations
    setSolutionState(resultOfCurrentComputations); // update React state every iteration
    await sleep(0); // unblock UI by chunking compute
  }
}
```

I would like for the following interaction:

1. When a user clicks triggers `handleSubmit`, the computation starts.
2. The computation runs, updating state every so often, chunking the compute and allowing the UI to be responsive
3. If the user clicks triggers `handleCancel`, the computation process is killed.

One way to do this is to have a global variable, `allowedToRun`, and invoking `handleCancel` will set this to false. Then, inside `solve`, I can check for `while (computationNotDone && allowedToRun)`.

However, I would like to not use global variables, as I believe it suggests my code is designed poorly.

I would appreciate any advice on how to design this system without global variables.

Also, I would like to import `solve`, so I cannot use a module-level variable without wrapping it in an object, which I want to avoid.

Comment: "how to design this system better" is quite opinion-based, so not really on-topic here at Stack Overflow. In any case there's information missing here. What happens if you have multiple "copies" of your component mounted at once? If `computationNoDone` should be updated only once for all of them, a "global" (by which I assume you mean module-level) variable seems OK. If it's independent for each "copy" then you should use a ref instead.

Comment: Hi Robin, thank you for your response. I have edited the bottom question of my post to be worded more explicitly.

I will not have two components mounted at any point.

I would also like for solve to be defined outside this module, and imported in. This would not allow me to use a module-level variable unless I wrap it in an object, which I don't want to do, as it seems like bad practice.

Comment: you can't possibly define `solve` outside of a React component, assuming `setSolutionState` is a state-setting function returned by `useState`. At least not in the form you currently have it. It might work if you can pass in that setter function as an argument - but again the discussion is reaching a point where more detail as to exactly what you need to do is needed. I can't shake the feeling that there must be a better/simpler way to do whatever it is you're actually intending!

Comment: Robin, that detail has already been included in my code, please re-read

Comment: I appreciate that your question is well written compared to many on here, and thank you for that. However, I cannot really answer it in the form it is currently in. I have no idea what kind of computations you are actually doing here, what they are needed for, and what relation that has to how the UI of your component(s) should behave. Without knowing that, I find it impossible to suggest what you should be doing.